# Assign values to a 2D array using another 2D array as a index

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a 2D mxn array A and another 2D qxp array B. I want to assign value of 1 to A at each coordinate listed in B.

I know that I could firstly get the length of b at axis=0, and write a loop to do it such like A[B[i,0]][b[i,1]] = 1; but i am working on a big dataset, I want to see if there is any way to do this without a for loop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem, what do you mean by " I want to assign value of 1 to A at each .."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant: if I have a 2D array with all elements are zero, i want to assign some of the elements to be 1. The coordinates of these elements (whose values are supposed to be 1) are in another 2D array. In this case, how can I extract the coordinate and assign values without a for loop. Thanks again!

Comment: If you ask with clear example, you can find good solutions. And I think it is not possible without loop in 2D.

Comment: I am new here - still have not known how to import code here. But fortunately someone understood me. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly assign the values by passing the columns of B as indices of A. You don't need to loop through the rows of B.

```
A[B[:,0],B[:,1]]=1
```

Here's a more detailed example

```
A=np.zeros((4,4))

array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])

B=np.array([[2,1],[2,2],[0,2],[3,0]])

array([[2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [3, 0]])

# directly pass each of the columns of B as indices of A
A[B[:,0],B[:,1]] = 1

print(A)

array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I meant. I was trying a similar way but with A[B[:,0]][B[:,1]]=1, which is apparently incorrect....